# Calculating total distance covered in given area

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have little private research to perform (for non-profit organization). I have given certain area on the map (inregular shape) and tracks - which are basically object position (GPS) put every several seconds.
My task is to calculate total length of the tracks inside the area (in meters). Is there easy way to do it with postgis?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesnt have much information but in postgis you have a function to convert points into line.

- [ST_MakeLine](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)

And once you have a line you can calculate the length.

- [ST_Length](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html)

Comment: Perhaps he have to intersect the area and the lines, because he wants the length of the given line on the area. He can do this with **ST_Intersection**

Comment: @Ohlsen1980 yes, I told OP to give us more information. But he didn't respond